# IIS Web Server Single IP Multiple Sites

Tags: iis, web-server, rewrite, iis-8, bindings

IIS 8 / Windows Server 2012 R2

I am new to IIS and need some advice regarding hosting multiple sites on a server with a single IP address. Not sure if I should be using application pools or VDs, or how to configure the bindings.

My domain is `example.com`.

I want to host two separate websites on this single server with a single IP address.

- example.com/cars (asp application)
- example.com/sport (php application)

So far in my IIS Sites Manager I have the following structure;

```
- Sites
-- Default Website
-- Cars
-- Sport
```

In my `inetpub/wwwroot` I have created two folders `Cars` and `Sport` - these folders contain all the relevant files and folders for the sites.

I have tried to edit the site bindings but I can't seem to get the configuration correct. For the `/cars` website I've tried;

```
type: http
hostname: example.com
port: 80
IP Address: *
```

I'm not sure how to bind this to the `/cars` directory / url. Do I need to set the ANAME or CNAME?

Notes;

- I don't want to use port numbers in the urls.
- I don't want to use subdomains.

My desired result;

- someone visits `example.com` and they see a landing page
- someone visits `example.com/cars` and they see the cars website
- someone visits `example.com/sport` and they see the sport website

Comment: Off topic. This is a "I do not read the manual, do my work for me" question. Per site rules: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background Rather easy to go with cars.example.com and sport.example.com if you know how IIS site bindings work. Using virtual directories only makes it unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi I should have added I don't want to use subdomains. I will have a read of the resource you provided though :)